# Skip a command if it is stuck and continue with the next command without terminating batch job in windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, timeout

I have a batch script with multiple commands running sequentially.There is one particular command which takes longer occassionaly(sometimes even stuck for hours). I want to skip this command if its execution is longer than 10 minutes, and continue with the batch job programmatically. Right now, I am monitoring the command and manually feed in Ctrl+C and press "N" when asked ofr "Terminate batch job?". Please help me as how to identify whether the particular command is stuck and kill it and proceed with the rest of the batch job. Any leads will be helpful, and I am very new to windows batch scripting.

Thank you.

Comment: [possible cross-site duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53977026/how-to-set-timeout-for-a-command-in-cmd)

Comment: [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481210/skip-a-command-if-its-taking-too-long) (a bit simpler and better to understand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this one process does not seem to be necessary for the following
commands, you could launch it in parallel and out of the sequential
execution stream.

You can use the
[start command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start)
like this :

```
start command parameters
```

This one command will then execute in its own separate window,
and can also be terminated at need without affecting the rest
of the script.